# Open channel (LN) in Electrum testnet is not accessible?

Tags: lightning-network, electrum, testnet

I use Electrum wallet (version 4.3.2) on tesnet (apple desktop).
The testnet balance is 0.02 tBTC.
Under the 'Channels' tab, the option 'Open Channel' is there
but it is not clickable.

Is LN testnet supported by Electrum ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is different in latest version of Electrum, however I could reproduce the issue in version 4.3.2 and it works fine in version 4.3.0

[image: elctrum-ln-1]

[image: electrum-ln-2]

[image: electrum-ln-3]

Maybe you can create an issue in Electrum Github repo: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum

Comment: I had no problem with mainnet. My question was about testnet. Is your example with testnet or mainnet ?

Comment: I used testnet in my example.

Comment: I started Electrum with: open -n /Applications/Electrum.app --args --testnet
I can see the link "open channel" but it is not clickable !
I also sent 0.02 tBTC in a regular transaction. Is there a minimum to access Lightning ?